# How to install mod_ssl on windows server 2008 64bits

Tags: apache2, windows-server-2008, mod-ssl

We manage our own VM **Windows Server 2008 R2 STD 64 bits** which is use as a web server.

APACHE httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-no_ssl is install on it since the beggining cause this was the only self install file (MSI) that we found on Apache web site.

I now need to install an SSL Certificate. I ran into a couple of forum without getting the exact solution method to my situation.

I use OpenSSL to create our own Self Sign Certificate on purpose of this installation. **The issue is where can I find mod_ssl module that is missing ?** I have no experience yet (but it's never too late to get a start) with compiling binaries and where can I get some safe binaries for this module if order to continue in configuring this dawn SSL Certificate ? :)

On the same machine i'm also running :

> - php-5.3.13-Win32-VC9-x86
> - mysql-5.5.24-winx64
> - FileZilla_Server-0_9_41
> - hMailServer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I just took it (mod_ssl.so) from my dev. server under an WAMP solution. I'd uncomment the ssl_module line into httpd.conf as suppose and all Works fine on my production server with this module.